# Python 3 - Finding position of where to insert a string in a currently alphabetized document

Tags: python, list, csv, python-3.x, indexing

So I have a document currently with multiple different items in it that are separated by commas.

The first word of each line in the document is alphabetized so each line is alphabetized. I need to create a function that finds what index to insert a new string, keeping the alphabetical list in tact. In other words inserting it so it is still alphabetical.

I am using the following for loop to split each line at the comma.

```
infile = open("Brain.csv", "r")

for line in infile:
    line.split(",")
```

How can I go about this from here? The alphabetized word is at index[0] of course.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Do you have a a sorted list of unsorted lines? e.g. `[ ['alpha', 'zulu', 'epsilon'], ['beta', 'kappa'], ['kappa', 'beta'] ]` or is it a sorted list of sorted lines? If the latter, what do want to do if the inserted word would come before the first index?

Answer (score 2):

The [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module provides the [**`csv.reader`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and [**`csv.writer`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to read and write **csv file** without pain. That being said you can add item to your list and keep it sorted using the [**`bisect.insort`**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort) function.

```
form bisect import insort
import csv

with open('brain.csv') as f, \
     open('brain_rewrite.csv', 'w') as out:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    out_csv = csv.writer(out)
    for row in f_csv:
        g = sorted(i.strip() for i in row)
        insort(g, 'Foo') #here inserting word 'Foo' note that word case matter.
        out.writerow(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a file like this:

```
Michael, Monroe, Stephen
Shawn, Shila, Zed
```

Let's say you want to insert the name "Ted" to the second row, while preserving the alphabetical order. All you need to do is open the file, split the words, insert the word in the list, order the list and then append the values back together:

```
with open("Brain.csv", "r") as file:
    text = file.readlines()
text = [x.split(', ') for x in text]

text[1].append("Ted")
text[1].sort()

text = [", ".join(i) for i in text]

with open("Brain.csv", "w") as file:
    file.writelines(text)
```

and now when you open the file you'll see:

```
Michael, Monroe, Stephen
Shawn, Shila, Ted, Zed
```

Comment: Hey, first thanks for the reply! I think you everyone is a bit confused? I currently have a doc with names, info, info, info just on each line in a doc. It is alphabatized by the name but I have to do the following: The function returns an integer indicating the index in the list of names such that if you inserted the given string into the list at that index the list would still be in alphabetical order.

Comment: Good try but there is no need to sort a sorted list again for such tasks also using `readlines` is not a good idea as you can read the lines one by one and return the relative index, and if you want to insert a word you need to know the number of line and you can change a file in place with `fileinput` https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html

Answer (score 0):

You can think of letters as numbers. Like A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, etc. So you can check if 'A' > 'T', in order to keep it alphabetical. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its what that `bisect.bisect_left` is for :

Demo:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect_left([1,2,5,7],3)
2
>>> bisect.bisect_left([1,2,5,7],0)
0
>>> bisect.bisect_left([1,2,5,7],6)
3
```

> [*bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a))*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)
>
> Locate the insertion point for x in a to maintain sorted order.

No for a file you can do :

```
>>> import bisect
>>> import csv
>>> def index_finder(file_name,st)
...   with open("file_name", "rb") as csvfile:
...      spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...      for row in spamreader:
            yield bisect.bisect_left(row,st)
```

Then the result would be a generator contain all of the positions in each row that your sample string can be insert!

For get the all of indices you can do :

```
print list(index_finder("Brain.csv",sample_string))
```

Answer (score -1):

Tsk tsk..You started writing some code. Keep going! No need to ask people on the internet to solve your problems. You can do this!

Here are some helpful hints:

1. Retrieving the first word from every line and appending it to a list

   ```
   first_words = [f.split(",")[0] for line in infile]
   ```
2. How to alphabetically sort a list of strings

   ```
   sorted_first_words = sorted(first_words, key=str.lower)
   ```
3. Find the index of the newly added "first_word"

   ```
   sorted_first_words.index("<new first word>")
   ```

Comment: Hey, first thanks for the reply! I think you everyone is a bit confused? I currently have a doc with names, info, info, info just on each line in a doc. It is alphabatized by the name but I have to do the following: The function returns an integer indicating the index in the list of names such that if you inserted the given string into the list at that index the list would still be in alphabetical order.